# How to describe the situation in the question in correct English?

Tags: meaning, sentence

Suppose two sheets intersect at a line and there is a third sheet which passing through the line. As a result two points will be created in the line. Now I want to do the inverse operation, that is moving away the third sheet so that the two points will be eliminated. My question is how can I describe the inverse operation in a correct English language? I said moving away the third sheet, but I am not convinced about this expression.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, ***Huh?***

- In Euclidean geometry, a line and a <del>sheet</del> plane
  intersect in zero, one, or an infinite number of points. 
  What are you doing that yields two points of intersection?
- If a line and a plane have one point of intersection,
  then *moving* either object some distance *away* will not change that result. 
  ***Rotating*** either object so they become parallel
  will eliminate the intersection.

If you’re talking about ***taking away*** the plane
(*eliminating* the point of intersection,
because there’s nothing for the line to intersect with any more),
you can describe this operation by saying

- ***taking away*** the plane
- ***eliminating*** the plane
- ***removing*** the plane